# Is possible to tell the Apple TV to start an app or open the store from a iOS phone app?

Tags: ios, tvos

We have an iOS app and we are working on a companion Apple TV app. the Apple TV app is useless without the phone app. Is it possible for the phone app to query whether the app is installed on the Apple TV and to ask the Apple TV to either open the store or open the TV app?

Thanks.

Edit: What I'm looking for is something similar to DIAL. Or Roku for example has a command to check apps, and if mine isn't there I can tell it to open the store to install it.

Comment: I believe that you're asking if you can control the AppleTV from a remote device in order to make it perform arbitrary actions. This is not possible.

Comment: Not arbitrary actions, open store or open app. Like on most TVs I can select the TV inside the YouTube app on my phone and usually via DIAL Youtube will open the TV YouTube app and play the video on the TV. So does the Apple TV have something similar to DIAL?